# Import to. gltf

Tags: export, glass, gltf

've got a problem, i need to export a cocktail glass(with liquid) to. gltf, but when i export there is no texture folder(but i choose to create one, when i was exporting).
So in a nutshell: i choose to export my cocktail as a
. gltf embedded(.gltf+.bin+textures),but only bin file creates, and when my customer opens it, he can only see Black model(glass without transparancy ), with red(without transparancy) liquid in it.
Help, plzzz
Update №1:
i've used texture from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YQY-UyW6R8, it suited to my customer's needs, but the colour of the glass is slightly blue, how could i fix it?

Comment: Did you wire up the material for glTF export as described in [the Blender Manual glTF documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html)?  Also, adjacent volumetric materials (such as liquid & glass together) are very hard for even the most modern rasterizers to load and use, typically they require path tracing or ray tracing to look even remotely correct.

Comment: i've used texture from this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YQY-UyW6R8, it suited to my customer's needs, but the colour of the glass is slightly blue, how could i fix it?